# place result of one cell into adjacent cell

Tags: excel

I want to enter text into a cell based on the value of an adjacent cell, for example. If value of A1 is <24, B1 would display "the text I want" There may be different text depending on the value of A1.

I tried the following formula, based on an answer found on this site, but all that happens is the complete formula appears in the chosen cell?

```
IF(H11<=23,"Hard burning tendency towards fine, dusty clinker,difficult to form coating",IF(H11<28,"Good range, no specific issues", IF(H11>=28,  "Hard burning, tendency towards large clinker, balling and heavy coating"))
```

Comment: Did you put `=` character before your formula? `=IF(H11...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula (dont forget the "=" sign)

```
=IF(A1<24,"The text that you want.","A1 is greater or equal to 24")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a small table (named range `Tproperties`):

[image: SO25337925 example]

then applying a formula of this kind:

```
=VLOOKUP(H11,Tproperties,2)
```

If the named range is of workbook scope it could be placed almost anywhere in the same workbook.